# Зависает WinXP при загрузке в VirtualBox 4.0.2!

Tags: windows, virtualbox, ubuntu

Синий прогрессбар бегает и бегает на протяжении очень долго времени.
Приходиться перезапускать машину несколько раз, что бы повезло. А иногда бывает грузится нормально с первого раза.

Система:
Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS amd64

Comment: Система свежая?

Comment: Да система свежая.

Comment: Нужны логи машины для того чтобы что то сказать.

Comment: Поставьте 4.0.6 с оф. сайта, а затем поставьте драйвер командой /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup Но для этого нужна поддержка DKMS. Ставится из репов операционки. С опенсурсными версиями бокса из репов операционок у меня по жизни проблемы были. С официалкой - все оке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В меню окна с запускаемой виндой (да и с любой гостевой ОС) можно посмотреть лог. Попробуйте разобраться самостоятельно или лог в студию.